# Jax-RS: Optional Path Params are not accepted in combination with method annotation @GET @POST

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am using `jersey` with `jackson` via `maven`:

```
    <jackson.version>2.9.6</jackson.version>
    <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
    <jetty.version>9.2.11.v20150529</jetty.version>
     ....
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
      </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey Server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
     </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I have a service class with the following method + a POST Method:

```
@GET
@Path("{Prefix}{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc{p2:/?}{number: (([A-Za-z0-9]*)?)}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getMyToken(@Context ServletContext context, @Context Request request, @HeaderParam("If-None-Match") String ifMatch, @HeaderParam("Prefer") String prefer) {..}


@POST
@Path("{Prefix}{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc/{myValueVariable}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response setMyToken(@Context ServletContext context, @Context Request request, @HeaderParam("If-None-Match") String ifMatch, @HeaderParam("Prefer") String prefer) {..}
```

This `GET` Url **SHOULD** accept two optional parameters. E.g. the following URLs should match:

- P/**1**/abc/**MyNumber**
- P/abc/**MyNumber**
- P/**1**/abc

However, it seems like the first two urls are NOT matching - the second optional parameter seems not to be recognized (i get a 405 error - method is not called). I tested a lot of things and I realized that adding an additional parameter at the end leads to a match of my URL. So with the follwing method

```
@GET
@Path("{Prefix}{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc{p2:/?}{number: (([A-Za-z0-9]*)?)}/endPath")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getMyToken(@Context ServletContext context, @Context Request request, @HeaderParam("If-None-Match") String ifMatch, @HeaderParam("Prefer") String prefer) {..}
```

the following urls match:

- P/**1**/abc/**MyNumber**/endPath
- P/abc/**MyNumber**/endPath
- P/**1**/abc/endPath

I don't want to have this last parameter. How can I solve this issue? What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I further noticed that it works if I do not use the first place holder:

```
@GET
@Path("hardCodePrefix{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc{p2:/?}{number: (([A-Za-z0-9]*)?)}")
```

As soon as I try to replace the hardCodePrefix with a variable or a regex I have the problem as described above (URLs are not matching)

**EDIT2:**
The really strange thing is, that even the **.*** wildcard does not work...

```
@GET
@Path("hardCodePrefix{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc{p2:/?}{number: .*}")
```

So e.g. P/**1**/abc/ is matching and I get `/` for p2. However something like P/**1**/abc/2 does not work anymore.... (no matching method error)

---

**EDIT3: Finding - Optional Parameter of GET Method is not recognized if there is a POST Method existing**

Now, I made an ***interesting observation***. If I add an additonal `POST` Service to my service class the `GET` Service does NOT work (the `URL` P/abc/**MyNumber** returns no method found error), if I remove it works (the issues above occured because I was always using a POST method in addition):

```
@GET
@Path("{Prefix}{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc{p2:/?}{number: (([A-Za-z0-9]*)?)}")
public Response doAnything2() {
    return Response.ok("sdf").build();

}
/*with that code below the GET method does not work, if I remove it, it works*/
@POST
@Path("{Prefix}{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc/{yeah}")
public Response doAnything3() {
    return Response.ok("sdf").build();

}
```

The existance of the `POST` seems to disturb the working of the `GET` method: **Is this a bug of jersey?**

I test my code using `Postman` and I explicitly set `GET` method.
**How can I tackle this issues?**

**EDIT4: Limited Answer**

Given the following code:

```
@POST
@Path("{Prefix2}{p4:/?}{id8: ((\\d+)?)}/abc/{yeah}")
public Response doAnything3() {
    return Response.ok("sdf").build();

}

@GET
@Path("{Prefix}{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc{p2:/?}{number: (([A-Za-z0-9]*)?)}")
public Response doAnything2() {
    return Response.ok("sdf").build();

}
```

The `URL` `mypath/1/abc/dd` called with `GET` returns a Method not found error.
If I **change** the **method annotated with POST** to

```
/*adding the last to parameters as an optional parameters*/
@POST
@Path("{Prefix}{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc{p8:/?}{number: (([A-Za-z0-9]*)?)}"
public Response doAnything3() {
    return Response.ok("sdf").build();

}

@GET
@Path("{Prefix}{p:/?}{id: ((\\d+)?)}/abc{p2:/?}{number: (([A-Za-z0-9]*)?)}")
public Response doAnything2() {
    return Response.ok("sdf").build();

}
```

**solves the problem**. It is a dirty workaround (because the last parameter using `POST` should not be optional (see upper part of the question)). I do not know why this strange things happen -> the answer should clarify why this happens and a nice solution should be presented in the answer.

Comment: First thought: Did you try adding just the final "/" ?

Comment: Yes, did not work....